# How to get expired session data from disk with CGI::Session in Perl?

Tags: perl, session

I use CGI::Session and can't find the way how to retrieve expired sessions data from disk before I remove them. "Notice: All expired sessions are empty". But maybe there is the way how to reload them from disk or read this files. Help me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the driver you used. With the defaults:

```
perl -mCGI::Session::Serialize::default -MData::Dumper=Dumper -MFile::Slurp=read_file -e'
    for my $f (glob "/tmp/cgisess*") {
        print Dumper(CGI::Session::Serialize::default->thaw(read_file $f))
    }
'
```

Comment: Is this command line syntax? Would you please write the same in normal view? And also can we do this having only CGI::Session object, not file handler?